# Magento 2 .htaccses configuration for HTTP get request

Tags: magento2, rest-api, http-request, geturl, angularjs

I try to get list of modules to localhost with angularJS 2

After i check all code possibilities on angularJS 2 - i need some help with configuration.

HTTP GET request with AngularJS 2:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http,RequestOptions,Headers,Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

   @Component({
   selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})


export class HomePage {




 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController , public http:Http ,public headers : Headers)  {


let res;
let opt: RequestOptions;
// let headers = new Headers();


// myHeaders.set('app-id', 'c2549df0');
this.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer lb2f4joajo5daodd9u7lubemeq2fjh4l');
// this.http._defaultOptions.headers.set('Authorization', 'token');

// headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
// headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
// headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
// headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept")

// headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");

// myHeaders.append("X-Frame-Options","SAMEORIGIN");
// myHeaders.append("Content-Length","655");
// myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Pragma");

// myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Request-Headers",'application/json');

// Methods allowed when accessing the resource.
// myHeaders.append( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' ,'GET, POST, OPTIONS');

// Accept-Ranges →bytes
// Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
// Cache-Control →no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
// Connection →Keep-Alive
// Content-Length →655
// Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
// Pragma →no-cache
// Server →LiteSpeed
// X-Frame-Options →SAMEORIGIN
// X-Powered-By →PHP/7.0.16
// X-UA-Compatible →IE=edge

// var body = `username=refaelgold@gmail.com&password=Blacksheep20`;

opt = new RequestOptions({
  headers: headers
  // url: "http://www.mageplayground.tk/index.php/rest/V1/modules"
});


// let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
// let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });
// headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);
//
// let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
// return this._http
//   .get(this._url,options)
//   .map(res => console.log(res));
//

// this.http.get('http://www.mageplayground.tk/index.php/rest/V1/categories',opt).map((res:Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
//   // data => this.data,
//   err => console.error(err),
//   () => console.log(res)
// );


 this.http.get("http://www.mageplayground.tk/index.php/rest/V1/modules/",opt)
  .map((res:Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
   // data => this.actualVisits = data,
   // err => this.logError(err),
   () => console.log(res));


this.http.get(`https://conduit.productionready.io/api/profiles/eric`)
  .map((res:Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
  // data => this.data,
  err => console.error(err),
  () => console.log(res)
);
 }
```

My .htaccses is

```
 Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
 Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "86400"
 Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token"

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

i work for it for days and i cant get any solution from my hosting company of the site http://www.mageplayground.tk/

i try to make the get http request with postman and i get the data that i needed..

i try to make i regular get request without headers and i get data of unauthorized(401)

i try to make a call on productionready.io and i get data.

i try to change the .htaccses so many times but i still cant get access for it.

I googling for days - this group its my only hope.

related issue : [Angular JS2 REST API call with Magento 2 headers not send](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151724/angular-js2-rest-api-call-with-magento-2-headers-not-send)

Thanks